# Spotfire - How to hide a column in table visualization, even though I use this column to sort the rest of the columns

Tags: sorting, hide, spotfire

I have 5 columns which I am using in the table visualization.
I don't want to show the 5th column in the table visualization but this column will be used as a column to sort the rest of the columns.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by the column, then remove it. The sort order will be preserved!

Comment: Is there any option to hide. Because I don't want the user to see this column, but when export to excel they should be able to view this column?